# Cannot Compile StellaWare

Tags: embedded, arm

I am trying to develop applications with Eclipse / Linux for Stellaris Launchpad (`LM4F120`). I am following this guide: http://kernelhacks.blogspot.de/2012/11/the-complete-tutorial-for-stellaris.html

However, I can't compile StellarisWare with `make`:

```
adc.c:1: error: bad value (cortex-m4) for -mcpu= switch
adc.c:1: error: invalid floating point option: -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
```

Obviously for compilation 'cc' instead of `arm-*-gcc` is used. How can I circumvent this problem?

I am using `gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4`. I did the following things for both  a) the full StellarisWare Package (`SW-LM3S-9453.exe`) and the one for the Stellaris Launchpad (`SW-EK-LM4F120XL-9453.exe`):

```
1. Unzip: ../SW-*.zip
2. Try to compile: make
```

Comment: your compiler doesn't support cortex-m4.

Comment: gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_7-2012q4 should support it since it is used in various tutorials and by other arm developers creating applications for this processor.

Comment: then you are invoking the wrong gcc.

Comment: Yes, I kind of realized this fact as well. However, my problem is how to get gcc-arm-none-eabi to compile stellaware.

Answer (score 0):

please follow the instruction in the below article

http://www.embeddedcircle.com/stellaris-lm4f120-launchpad-compiling-in-ubuntu-12-04/

do not forget to set the compiler path as per instruction 4